# Assigning case roles via webform?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, civicase

I have inherited a Drupal + CiviCRM 4.7 site which uses CiviCase to track applicants for an award. The applicant is the case client, and each case (nomination) has up to three judges assigned, who are supposed to submit scores on the case itself.

On the existing Case Type "Nomination" I have created the Case Role "Judge [for]" to link the judge and the applicant.

Right now, these assignments are handled manually, and I would like to set up a Webform CiviCRM interface for it; I cannot, however, find a way to add these role assignments. The webform has four contacts (for the applicant and each of up to three judges), but there is no way to set up the Judge role, only Case Client and Case Creator.

[image: Webform CiviCRM configuration for Cases]

I tried setting this up in Rules using relationships, but it creates general relationships, not case relationships, and so the Judges do not have permission to view and modify the case.

Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its an issue with Webform module itself where it doesn't show relationship if you have relationship type label and name different.

Developer from Circle-Interactive submitted a [fix](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/237) for this today. Can try applying [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/237.patch) if it displays the relationship type on case tab of the webform?

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Bravo! I didn't realize the additional roles were supposed to show up there, but they do show up now, and the form makes the correct assignments accordingly.

Comment: Cheers, glad to hear that the fix helped you :)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to comment on PR(https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/237) so that it gets merged into module?

Comment: Had to create a new GH account (I've only been using my regular one for work, but this is a side project). but it's done.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nice catch, and the general name-vs-label problem has been driving me nuts for years. The problem is actually in core, but the PR is an interesting alternate way of dealing with it.